# Преобразование class в массив byte []

Tags: java, android-studio

При  работе через Bluetooth получаю ответ от оборудования по сокету в формате массива `byte[] buffer`.

Этот ответ физически представляет собой запись данных разной длины (byte, short, int).

Для дальнейшей работы с данными есть класс:

```
public static class opstate  {
    // 1-4 RG
    byte actuator;
    byte logical;
    byte physical;
    byte optionsPart1_ActChannell;
    byte fault1623;
    byte notReady;

    byte fault0007;
    byte fault0815;

    // 5 RG
    byte torqPercent;                   //  процент момента (знаковое число 1 байт)
    byte openPercent;                   //  процент открытия арматуры (беззнаковое число 1 байт)

    // 6-7
    int absPositionCode;                //  Код положения привода (беззнаковое число 8 байтов).

    //8-9
    int relPositionCode;                //  Относительный код положения привода.
    //10
    short absTorqCode;                    // Код момента.Беззнаковое число размером 2 байта.

    //11
    short relTorqCode;    
}
```

Есть ли способ корректно преобразовать экземпляр такого класса в формат массива `byte[]` для передачи его в устройство и наоборот, декодировать нужные данные из массива `byte[]` при условии что в массиве они лежат в том же порядке что и записаны в классе?

Comment: Я бы добавил сеттер и геттер. Сеттер из байтов создает объект, правильно раскидывая байты по полям. Геттер соответственно правильно упаковывает объект в массив байтов.

Comment: Добавить то можно, а вот как упаковывать я пока не могу понять, учитывая что вручную по одному полю за другим это слишком долго, в реальности там гораздо больше переменных и классов несколько, которых так надо кодировать/декодировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это же элементарно Ватсон:

Объект в массив `byte`:

```
public byte[] obj2Byte(Object myObject) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
    objStream.writeObject(myObject);
    return byteStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Массив `byte` в объект:

```
public Object byte2Obj(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteStream);
    return objStream.readObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли способ корректно преобразовать экземпляр такого класса в
>   формат массива byte[] для передачи его в устройство и наоборот,
>   декодировать нужные данные из массива byte[] при условии что в массиве
>   они лежат в том же порядке что и записаны в классе?

Да есть способ.
Если ваш формат кастомный. Написать самому encode\decode 
Если ваш формат общепринятый - могут быть компиляторы классов, которые по схеме данных автоматически напишут всю логику перевода byte[] в класс и обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Сериализация и правда работает, но она очень много создает  служебной информации в массиве так что нашел метод который работает с чистыми  значениями в массиве - `ByteBuffer` и его методы `getShort()` и `getInt()`.